Hide the label text

I apply the bootstrap 5 form-floating to an input field, how can I hide the label not be showed outside the input box?

You should add .overflow-hidden to your div.form-floating wrappers.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/overflow/


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
    
      
      <div class="form-floating mb-3 overflow-hidden">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
        <label for="floatingInput">Really Long Email address label</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-floating overflow-hidden">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password">
        <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
      </div>
      
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



